# Drupal - Acquia Marina 3 - block title style configure settings

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I have made a sub theme to Acquia Marina and would like to change the **default setting** on the block configuration page from **none** to **Blue rounded title background with white text**. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, afaik, to do this with Skinr. What you can do right now is look for the selector you're looking for in the theme .css, apply it by default to all blocks, then add proper css to cancel the styles to each skinr alternative.

I know, it is a pain. Skinr is evolving, and I hope it will change for the best.